# How do I start java in "cli mode"

Tags: java, command-line-interface

Python has a nice feature where I just type "python" in sh and I get an interactive way of testing Python code.

How do I do that with Java?

I'm on Mac 10.9 if that makes any difference.

Comment: Java!=Python and AFAIU offers no such mode.

Comment: Maybe something like this? http://stackoverflow.com/a/3504710/1328300

Comment: Why would this have been downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

Java does not have a "CLI mode" like Python.

There's [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) which is probably similar to what you mean, but it seems that has not been updated for a long time.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing built into Java. However Beanshell might be what you are looking for:

> You can use BeanShell interactively for Java experimentation and debugging as well as to extend your applications in new ways.

http://www.beanshell.org/intro.html

It however doesn't look like there's much development going on these days and other approaches (such as the mentioned Jython one) might be more practical.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is called a "[REPL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop)" which is short for "Read–eval–print loop".

Since Java 9 there is a REPL bundled with Java, it is called `jshell`.

```
$ jshell
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.2
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> int x = 4
x ==> 4

jshell> int y = 9
y ==> 9

jshell> x + y
$3 ==> 13

jshell> /exit
|  Goodbye
$
```

Answer (score -2):

Python is scripting language means that it is not compiled language but it is interpreted language.

[Wikipedia definition for Interpreted language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpreted_language)

While Java is compiled language and you will never find such a feature link in python interactive mode, becuase you must write the whole application structure main class to make your app run. So instead you can use an IDE like eclipse , or netbeans.

[Compiled Language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compiled_language)

And also you can refere to stackoverflow link 
[Compiled vs. Interpreted Languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3265357/compiled-vs-interpreted-languages)

Comment: Slight digression, but related question to this point: If it is impossible as you say, then how is it possible for this answer to exist? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2605051/193601

Comment: This distinction is irrelevant. Scala is *also* a "compiled language" and yet provides a [REPL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Read%E2%80%93eval%E2%80%93print_loop) - other counter-examples to this reply include SML, Haskell and even C# in an "Interactive Window" when debugging. Conversely, Perl is a "scripting language" and has no core REPL support. There is also [BeanShell](http://www.beanshell.org/) for Java which is sorta like a Java REPL.